# ng-model with complex nested json object and arrays

Tags: angularjs, drupal

Here's my scope:

```
$scope.form_state = { values: {

  title: 'Hello',
  body: {
    und: [ { value: 'World' } ]
  }

} };
```

Here's my view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form_state.values['title']" />
<textarea ng-model="form_state.values['body']"></textarea>
```

**Hello** is rendered properly in the text field, and `[object Object]` is rendered in the text area, which means there is at least something in there...

So why don't either of these `ng-models` work for placing **World** in the text area?

```
form_state.values['body["und"][0].value']
form_state.values['body.und[0].value']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing it like this:

```
form_state.values['body'].und[0].value
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdg7yho/)